# On solving time dependent potentials of geometrically changing barriers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, elliptic-functions, potential-theory, hyperbolic-equations

I'm asking this question on maths SE as I believe it is a question that more to do with math than physics, cause only the concept is from the latter.

Consider a paraboloid potential barrier with maximum height, V, changing with time into a Hyperboloid potential barrier (with the same constant height, V, at its saddle point), which further changes into an ellipsoidal barrier.

**Mathematical formulation:**

> Consider a n-dimensional Schrödinger equation of the form:
>   $$\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial{x_{k}^{2}}}-V(x,t)\right]\psi(x,\alpha)=\lambda(\alpha)\psi(x,\alpha)$$
>   where the potential $V(x,t)$ depends on the column vector $x$ belonging to the n-dimensional complex space $C^{n}$
>
> Now let the elliptic potential be: the 2-gap Lamé potential 
>   $$V_{e}(x,t)=2\wp(x-x_{1}(t))+2\wp(x-x_{2}(t))+2\wp(x-x_{3}(t))$$
>
> Now this potential varies with time and changes into a hyperbolic potential of the form:
>   $$V_{h}(x,t)=aV_{0}coth(\alpha x)+bV_{1}coth^{2}(\alpha x)-cV_{2}cosech(\alpha x)+d-cos(\alpha t)$$ where $a,b,c,d$ and $V_{0},V_{1},V_{2}$ are constants.

How would the 3-d graph of the Lamé potential look like?

How do I handle this system, as I want the change of the potential functions(as a function of time)to be continuous, I.e., the elliptic 2-gap lamé potential changing to the hyperbolic potential and further to a parabolic potential with the wavefunction being continuous in every $\epsilon$ part of the barrier for every $\delta$ change in time. How would I solve such a system of time varying potential?

**edit**

Online, people suggest the following:

> Exact solutions depend on symmetries that one must discover.

Could anyone please shed some light upon the meaning of this statement.

Comment: I think, at best; only an approximation is available. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation

Comment: @Ranc Yeah I'm aware of the WKB and semiclassical approximation used, which is the main reason why I want to know if there is another method of solving the system without any approximation. Do you know of any paper which address this problem?